# Function takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to run some python code on a raspberry-pi in order to simulate different sensors. When calling a function twice, I'm being told that I'm providing too many arguments. I will have approximately 20 different functions all calling this `outputPWM` function, but I have just shown two functions as an example.

I've only started using python this week, so I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. If I can clear the `outputPWM` function of arguments in some way before the next call or I may have some fundamental flaw in my code

```py
def outputPWM(n1,i):
    num1 = (n1.get()) 
    result = int(num1)
    dutycycle = result 
    print(List[25])
    List[i].start(0)
    List[i].ChangeDutyCycle(dutycycle)
    print("Duty cycle is %d" % dutycycle)
    print("output is on port %d" %i)

def control():
    ControlReturn = tk.StringVar()  
    ControlLabel = tk.Label(master, text="Control Return Air Temperature (Degrees Celcius)").grid(row=0, column=0)  
    ControlResult = tk.Label(master)  
    ControlEntry = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=ControlReturn).grid(row=0,column=2)
    global outputPWM
    outputPWM=partial(outputPWM,ControlReturn,20)  
    buttonCal = tk.Button(master, text="Enter", command=outputPWM).grid(row=0, column=3) 

def display():   
    DisplayReturn = tk.StringVar()  
    DisplayLabel = tk.Label(master,text="Display Return Air Temperature (Degrees Celcius)").grid(row=1, column=0)  
    DisplayEntry = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=DisplayReturn).grid(row=1,column=2)
    global outputPWM
    outputPWM= partial(outputPWM,DisplayReturn,25)
    buttonCal = tk.Button(master, text="Enter", command=outputPWM).grid(row=1, column=3)

display()
control()
```

The error I receive is :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: outputPWM() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you are creating a partial function, give it a name other than the global outputPWM:

```
global outputPWM
outputPWM_ = partial(outputPWM, ControlReturn, 20)
buttonCal = tk.Button(master, text="Enter", command=outputPWM_).grid(row=0, column=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is executed twice, first time in `display()` and second time in `control()` (with slightly different parameters, but that does not matter)

```
global outputPWM
outputPWM=partial(outputPWM,ControlReturn,20)
```

It replaces the original function with derived partial one which adds 2 args. The second round replaces that partial function with another partial one derived from the first partial function. The resulting function adds 2+2 args in two steps. That is the source of "takes 2 args (4 given)" error.

The solution is not reusing the same name (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and not using `global` unless it is not really necessary.